# How to search usages of methods/fields in libraries in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

File structure:

```
Project Files: ...
Libraries:
| ...
| minecraft.jar
| | net.minecraft
| | | MinecraftVersion (class)
| | | | field INSTANCE
| | | | method create()
| | | | ...
| | ...
```

For example, I want to search where the method `MinecraftVersion.create()` is invoked or where the field `MinecraftVersion.INSTANCE` is used in `minecraft.jar`.

What I did in the past is to decompile `minecraft.jar` and manually pack it to an IntelliJ project. But it's too unconvienient. Using `Ctrl+Alt+F7`, `Ctrl+Alt+Shift+F7` and `Alft+F7` do not work.

Comment: try CTRL+click on the method/instance name.

Comment: You are kidding me :D @ThilankaD

Comment: Have you tried?

Comment: Tried. Multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure the **Scope** for the **Find Usages** action to also include **Project libraries**:

1. Press ⌥⇧⌘F7 to open the Find Usages dialog.
2. In the Find Usages dialog, in the Scope field, select a scope for your search:

[image]

If IntelliJ IDEA doesn't return any results, it will display a message suggesting that you opt for more options:

[image]

You can follow the link or press ⌥⇧⌘F7 to open the Find Usages dialog again and set a new scope for your search.

See [Manage the Find Usages scope](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/find-highlight-usages.html#find_usage_scope).

Answer (score 0):

Even tho this isn't ideal, you could decompile minecraft.jar, then use notepad++ to search all the files in the directory and sub-directories for that.

Comment: Using npp seems to be a good idea. However, it is not intelligent nor intellisense -- that's what I want and why I questioned